# Is there a way to remove all colliders at once?

Tags: collision

I have a large scene made in Blender, where many of the objects have mesh colliders. However, mesh colliders are a bit inefficient compared to using primitives. I would like to get rid of all mesh colliders, so that when I export to a game engine I can manually approximate the collisions using primitives such as cubes, added in-engine.

Is there a way to remove all colliders at once? If not, how do I remove colliders from specific objects? I don't see anything enabled in the "Physics Properties", but the objects still have colliders when imported into a game engine. I'm using Blender 2.83 and Godot 3.2.2 (both are betas).

Answer (score 1):

This script removes all colliders from the active view layer :

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.view_layer.objects:
    if obj.rigid_body:
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
        bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_remove()
```

[How to run a script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11604548/7092409)

Comment: I ran the script and all of the colliders are still there. Here is the Blender file, with the script included: http://www.mediafire.com/file/ctdf26rxzagb5po/core.blend/file

Comment: Could you add a screenshot in your question about what your mesh colliders are and on which objects they are applied ? I can't find any in your file

Comment: When I export to GLB and import into Godot, there are still colliders that show up. Here is the branch I am working on which includes Blender files, GLB files, and them imported into a Godot project (requires Git LFS) https://github.com/aaronfranke/tps-demo/tree/remake

Comment: Here is a screenshot. Only a few objects have colliders, including these pipes. I want to get rid of all of them. https://i.imgur.com/ykobezC.png

Comment: Okay so you are not using blender's rigidbody system for your colliders, my bad. I think this should be treated in godot when importing rather than in blender. What add-on do you use to export in GLB format ?

Comment: None, I am using the built-in GLB exporter in Blender 2.83 beta. Godot does not have an import option to remove colliders, and removing them manually is non-trivial.

Comment: Alright, sorry I can't help you then :(